# Ubuntu Touch on Laptops

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Does Ubuntu Touch Support non-touch devices, such as Laptops? How about Mice & Keyboards?
I know it sounds odd but it would be cool to get away from the normal Ubuntu interface.
Thanks